# Mapping XML succeeds but object has empty values

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm using RKXMLReaderSerialization and trying to map an XML response from my server to an object. It succeeds, but the object from the mapping result just has empty values.

Here's the text/xml response I'm trying to map from my server:

```
<Provision version="1.0">
  <FileInfoWrapper>
    <FileUrl>SomeFile.zip</FileUrl>
    <FileName>SomeFile.zip</FileName>
    <FileSha1>oi7NK/rFLL6dXqcu7ahaNfKsGkE=</FileSha1>
    <FileSize>52220448</FileSize>
    <Version>13</Version>
    <Vital>true</Vital>
  </FileInfoWrapper>
</Provision>
```

Here's my model object:

```
@interface FileInfoWrapper : NSObject

@property NSString *fileUrl;
@property NSString *fileName;
@property NSString *fileSha1;
@property long fileSize;
@property NSString *version;
@property BOOL vital;

@end
```

I've added RKXMLReaderSerialization:

```
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKXMLReaderSerialization class] forMIMEType:RKMIMETypeTextXML];
[[self objectManager] setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"application/json,text/xml"];
```

I think I have the mapping and response descriptor setup correctly:

```
RKObjectMapping *fileInfoMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[FileInfoWrapper class]];
[fileInfoMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"FileUrl":        @"fileUrl",
 @"FileName":       @"fileName",
 @"FileSha1":       @"fileSha1",
 @"FileSize":       @"fileSize",
 @"Version":        @"version",
 @"Vital":          @"vital"}];
RKResponseDescriptor *fileInfoResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:fileInfoMapping
                                                                                                method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                           pathPattern:nil
                                                                                               keyPath:@"Provision.FileInfoWrapper"
                                                                                           statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[[self objectManager] addResponseDescriptor:fileInfoResponseDescriptor];
```

But when I call:

```
[[self objectManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"static/download/Installer.info.xml"
                            parameters:nil
                               success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                   NSLog(@"****Success!****");
                                   NSLog(@"mappingResult: %@", mappingResult);
                                   FileInfoWrapper *fileInfo = [mappingResult firstObject];
                                   NSLog(@"URL: %@", [fileInfo fileUrl]);
                                   NSLog(@"Name: %@", [fileInfo fileName]);
                                   NSLog(@"SHA1: %@", [fileInfo fileSha1]);
                                   NSLog(@"Size: %lx", [fileInfo fileSize]);
                               }
                               failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                   NSLog(@"****Failure!****");
                               }];
```

All the values are null:

```
I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:180 GET 'http://example.com/static/download/Installer.info.xml'
I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:250 GET 'http://example.com/static/download/Installer.info.xml' (200 OK / 1 objects) [request=0.1080s mapping=0.0060s total=0.1226s]
****Success!****
mappingResult: <RKMappingResult: 0x10064b190, results={
    "Provision.FileInfoWrapper" = "<FileInfoWrapper: 0x10065f780>";
}>
URL: (null)
Name: (null)
SHA1: (null)
Size: 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I turned on RestKit/ObjectMapping logging and got some additional info:

```
D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:377 Executing mapping operation for representation: {
    Provision =     {
        FileInfoWrapper =         {
            FileName =             {
                text = "SomeFile.zip";
            };
            FileSha1 =             {
                text = "oi7NK/rFLL6dXqcu7ahaNfKsGkE=";
            };
            …
}
 and targetObject: (null)
T restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:320 Examining keyPath 'Provision.FileInfoWrapper' for mappable content...
D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:300 Found mappable data at keyPath 'Provision.FileInfoWrapper': {
    FileName =     {
        text = "SomeFile.zip";
    };
    FileSha1 =     {
        text = "oi7NK/rFLL6dXqcu7ahaNfKsGkE=";
    };
    …
}
D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:231 Asked to map source object {
    FileName =     {
        text = "SomeFile.zip";
    };
    FileSha1 =     {
        text = "oi7NK/rFLL6dXqcu7ahaNfKsGkE=";
    };
    …
} with mapping <RKObjectMapping:0x10025e6b0 objectClass=FileInfoWrapper propertyMappings=(
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x10025ebc0 FileSha1 => fileSha1>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x10025ed90 FileName => fileName>"
    …
)>
D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:952 Starting mapping operation...
T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:953 Performing mapping operation: <RKMappingOperation 0x10068f730> for 'FileInfoWrapper' object. Mapping values from object {
    FileName =     {
        text = "SomeFile.zip";
    };
    FileSha1 =     {
        text = "oi7NK/rFLL6dXqcu7ahaNfKsGkE=";
    };
    …
} to object <FileInfoWrapper: 0x10068f290> with object mapping (null)
T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:550 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'FileUrl' to 'fileUrl'
T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:431 Found transformable value at keyPath 'FileUrl'. Transforming from type '__NSDictionaryM' to 'NSString'
D restkit.object_mapping:RKPropertyInspector.m:130 Cached property inspection for Class 'FileInfoWrapper': {
    fileName =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = fileName;
    };
    fileSha1 =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = fileSha1;
    };
    …
}
T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:583 Skipped mapping of attribute value from keyPath 'FileUrl to keyPath 'fileUrl' -- value is unchanged ((null))
T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:550 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'FileSha1' to 'fileSha1'
T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:431 Found transformable value at keyPath 'FileSha1'. Transforming from type '__NSDictionaryM' to 'NSString'
T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:583 Skipped mapping of attribute value from keyPath 'FileSha1 to keyPath 'fileSha1' -- value is unchanged ((null))
…
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you have to map from the text node. This post had the same problem:

[RestKit 0.20-pre3 with RKXMLReaderSerialization and XMLReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819929/restkit-0-20-pre3-with-rkxmlreaderserialization-and-xmlreader)

Changing the mapping to:

```
[fileInfoMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"FileUrl.text":        @"fileUrl",
 @"FileName.text":       @"fileName",
 @"FileSha1.text":       @"fileSha1",
 @"FileSize.text":       @"fileSize",
 @"Version.text":        @"version",
 @"Vital.text":          @"vital",}];
```

did it.

Comment: Wow!!! That was the problem I was having. There is no way I could figure this out looking at the XML only.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't set the accept header to JSON if you're expecting XML. I also don't think you can set a comma separated list like that (not 100% sure on that though). If the server sends JSON as a result of your accept header then RestKit will be happy with the response but will likely fail to actually do any mapping (which appears to be what you see).

Turn on trace logging to get more info about the response and the mapping:

```
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);
```

Your mapping code does look correct.

Comment: I kept JSON in the accept header since I have other paths that produce JSON. I need to accept both. I turned on the logging and added some more info to the post. Thanks!

Comment: So you need more info from the trace logging to find out what's happening.